# In ES6, export let m = 1; and m = 1; export m; why the former is true, the latter is false?

Tags: javascript

```
 export let m = 1;
```

```
let m = 1; 
export m;
```

I know the export of ES6 Module needs to be an interface. The former export an interface, and the latter export number 1.
I want to know why the former export an interface? I guess priority of operations, but I am not sure.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a typo. That will be `export` not `expoort`.

Comment: it's `export { m }` in the second case

Comment: I think your actual question is "Why is `export` only allowed in front of declarations?"

Comment: `export let m = 1;` and `let m = 1; export { m };` are the same

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo. That will be `export` not `expoort`

Also you should use 
`export default m` 
or 
`export { m }` in the second case.

You can also check details from this [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of exports:

- Named exports (Zero or more exports per module)
- Default exports (One per module)

The one you're asking about is a named export.

Here's an example for both named and default exports

```
export const a = 1; // named export
export const b = 2; // named export
export const c = 3; // named export
const d = 4;
export default d; // default export
```

To import these in another file :

```
import {a,b,c} from './file';
```

or

```
import d from './file';
```

or

```
import d, {a,b,c} from './file';
```